# How to use 'for' loop in velocity template?

Tags: java, templates, velocity

I just googled for 'for loop', but it looks like velocity has 'foreach' only.

How do I use 'for loop' in velocity template?

Comment: The best answer is bellow the fold, by @serg : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5683891/299843

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There's only `#foreach`. You'll have to put something iterable on your context. E.g. make `bar` available that's an array or `Collection` of some sort:

```
#foreach ($foo in $bar)
    $foo
#end
```

Or if you want to iterate over a number range:

```
#foreach ($number in [1..34])
    $number
#end
```

Comment: // Thanks! I don't understand why they don't have most basic loop!

Comment: foreach is the most basic kind of loop.  for is an advanced one.

Comment: Note that ranges in Velocity are inclusive, so that second example will loop 34 times, with `$number` going from 1 to 34.

Answer (score 46):

Wanted to add that iteration information inside foreach loop can be accessed from special `$foreach` property:

```
#foreach ($foo in $bar)
    count: $foreach.count
    index: $foreach.index
    first: $foreach.first 
    last:  $foreach.last
#end
```

(last time I checked `last` contained a bug though)

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I needed to write the index in my template. Thanks for this post!

Comment: If you're stuck with Velocity 1.6 (f.e. as used by Confluence), only `$velocityCount` and `$velocityHasNext` are available (http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.6/user-guide.html#Loops)

Comment: You can also get at these variables from within nested loops with `$foreach.parent.whatever` e.g. `$foreach.parent.parent.index` gets the index of the outer loop from within a triply nested foreach loop.

Answer (score 8):

I found the solution when i was trying to loop a list.
Put the list in another class and create getter and setter for the list obj.
e.g

```
public class ExtraClass {
    ArrayList userList = null;

    public ExtraClass(List l) {
        userList = (ArrayList) l;
    }

    public ArrayList getUserList() {
        return userList;
    }

    public void setUserList(ArrayList userList) {
        this.userList = userList;
    }

}
```

Then for velocity context put the Extraclass as the input.
eg.

```
  ExtraClass e = new ExtraClass(your list);
VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
```

context.put("data", e);
Within template

```
#foreach ($x in $data.userList)
        $x.fieldname    //here $x is the actual obj inside the list
    #end
```

Comment: Is this applicable for maps?