# "for" loop in velocity template

Tags: loops, for-loop, velocity

I already posted a similar question a week ago on [How to use 'for' loop in velocity template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683690/how-to-use-for-loop-in-velocity-template).

So...basically I can't use 'for' loop in a velocity template.

Let's say I have a variable that holds integer 4. I want to display something four times using that variable. How do I do it in a velocity template?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Try to do it like this:

```
#set($start = 0)
#set($end = 4)
#set($range = [$start..$end])
#foreach($i in $range)
   doSomething
#end
```

The code has not been tested, but it should work like this.

Answer (score 40):

You don't have to use the `#set` like the accepted answer.  You can use something like this:

```
#foreach($i in [1..$end])
    LOOP ITERATION: $i
#end
```

If you want zero indexed you do have to use one `#set` because you can't subtract one within the range operator:

```
#set($stop = $end - 1)
#foreach($i in [0..$stop])
    LOOP ITERATION: $i
#end
```

Comment: That second one doesn't work. You can't inline a -1 in a range operator. You'd have to `#set($foo = $end - 1)` first, then use `#foreach($i in [0..$foo])`

Comment: I just submitted an edit. `#set($stop=$end-1)` doesn't work, and `$stop` remains null. Spaces matter in Velocity. To correctly assign it, use `#set($stop = $end - 1)` or `#set($stop=$end - 1)`. `#set($stop=$end -1)` is also invalid

Answer (score 6):

Just to add another option to Stephen Ostermiller's answer, you can also create a zero-indexed loop using `$foreach.index`. If you want to loop `$n` times:

```
#foreach($unused in [1..$n])
    zero indexed: $foreach.index
#end
```

here, `$unused` is unused, and we instead use `$foreach.index` for our index, which starts at 0.

We start the range at 1 as it's inclusive, and so it will loop with `$unused` being [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], whereas `$foreach.index` is [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].

See [the user guide](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html#foreach-loop) for more.